# How to seperate the zipcode from the mailing address?

Tags: .net, regex, c#-4.0

I want to separate the zipcode from the mailing address. Mailing address can be variable length but, as usual zipcode will be at the end. we don't have any special characters to separate zipcode from the address.

Zipcode can be the length of 8/9/10 digits. (int datatype). Sometimes Zipcode may not be available.

can you please share if you have any idea to do it by using C# programing or Regular expressions or any other useful.

Comment: It would be helpful to see some example addresses you want to successfully match.

Comment: street-number street-type direction street-name unit unit-type city zipcode. it is the address format. In the above street-name only the mandatory field. ex: 12312 avenue N street-name 9999999999

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to match numbers (and dashes?) at the end of a string, you can do so with a regular expression such as:

`[0-9\-]+$`

If you want to tolerate white space between the zipcode and end of string, you could use an expression like:

`([0-9\-]+)\s*$`

Usage would be something like:

```
var m = Regex.Match(input, @"([0-9\-]+)\s*$");
if(m.Success)
{
    //parse m.Groups[1]
}
```